# This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl"

Tags: 18.04, snap, wayland

Suddenly robo3t doesn't start,

Error Message

```
usama@usama:~$ robo3t-snap
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "wayland-egl"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Help me with this issue.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling as suggested by the error message? Was Robo3T working for you previously (and if so, what changed in your Ubuntu environment)? It looks like [Robo3T-snap](https://github.com/shalev67/Robo3T-snap) is a third party packaging of Robo3T so you probably want to [report this issue to the Robo3T-snap developer](https://github.com/shalev67/Robo3T-snap/issues). Alternatively you could try the [Linux download of Robo3T](https://robomongo.org/download) from robomongo.org.

Comment: most of my apps show the same message, I couldn't understand what's wrong. and finally, I format and re-install ubuntu :-(

Comment: This happened also to me today using `telegram-desktop`. It happened really suddenly and unexpected. I don't know if snap, wayland, or Telegram was the cause; but I didn't have any change/update on them. This seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

One eternity later...

You should check [environment variables.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Environment_variables)

The most easy way to check if it works by setting an environment variable, is to write `env VARIABLE_NAME=value` before the command or program that you want to run.

For example:

```bash
env QT_QPA_PLATFORM="xcb" robo3t-snap
```